# Intellij not respecting tool:expected-type annotations in custom Spring namespace

Tags: spring, xsd, intellij-idea

I created a custom Spring namespace.  It works fine as far as deploying properly, etc., but Intellij isn't validating `tool:expected-type` annotations on bean references (i.e. I can reference a bean of any type and Intellij doesn't highlight the attribute in red as it should) nor is it providing any autocomplete on these references.

Other `tool` features seem to work fine, such as `tool:exports`.

Intellij recognizes my schema, and gives  all other autocomplete features other than on the expected-type refs.

Intellij is also successfully parsing the custom elements into the various desired beans when selecting the `Parse custom bean` command.

Here is a trimmed-down version of what I want, but this is what I'm currently trying:

```
<xsd:element name="routed-channel">
    <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:appinfo>
            <tool:annotation>
                <!-- This part works - other bean refs that require a MessageChannel can reference this channel -->
                <tool:exports type="org.springframework.integration.core.MessageChannel" />
            </tool:annotation>
        </xsd:appinfo>
    </xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="recipient" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:attribute name="channel" type="xsd:string" use="required">
                        <xsd:annotation>
                            <xsd:appinfo>
                                <tool:annotation kind="ref">
                                    <!-- This part does not work - IntelliJ allows a any reference here -->
                                    <tool:expected-type type="org.springframework.integration.core.MessageChannel" />
                                </tool:annotation>
                            </xsd:appinfo>
                        </xsd:annotation>
                    </xsd:attribute>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
        </xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:attribute name="id" type="xsd:string" use="required"/>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA v11.1.3.

If anyone can provide some clue as to what might be wrong or how it can be fixed, it would be great.

Comment: Please try adding kind="ref" attribute to the tool:annotation tag.

Comment: @PeterGromov Sorry, that was an error in my copying and pasting, but I have `kind="ref"` in my real schema.  I'm updating the questions now.  Thanks for pointing that out, though.

Comment: @PeterGromov I added the real element definition that I'm currently using.  Again, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: It might be a bug then. What if you define the channel attribute on the top-level element (routed-channel) and not its recipient sub-element? Will this reference be recognized and constrained by IDEA?

Comment: @PeterGromov That still is not constrained.

Comment: Strange. Could you please prepare a small sample project demonstrating the issue and file a bug with it to http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/dashboard ?

Comment: @PeterGromov Sure.  It may take me a few days to get around to it, though, as this issue is around a nice-to-have design feature aimed at reducing the potential for future configuration errors.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upgraded to IntelliJ 12 and this is no longer a problem.  So the answer is:  upgrade IntelliJ!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a related bug report in Intellij bugbase : http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-87187